# How to use the build script with kickstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate, kickstrap

I've just started playing around with Kickstrap and I can't get the build script working.

Following the instructions [here](http://ajkochanowicz.github.com/Kickstrap/h5bp.html), I create a new Kickstrap project (by just unziping the files to a directory) and then going to site1/build/ and running:

```
ant build
```

but the build fails with the following errors:

```
-js.all.minify:
     [echo] Minifying scripts
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/bob/site1/intermediate/js
    [apply] /home/bob/site1/js/tests/server.js:10: ERROR - Parse error. missing name after . operator
    [apply]       .use(connect.static(__dirname + '/../../'));
    [apply]                           ^
    [apply] 
    [apply] 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
    [apply] Result: 1
```

and

```
-less:
     [echo] Converting LESS to CSS...
     [echo] Minifying css...
 [checksum] Could not find file /home/bob/site1/intermediate/css/style.less.min.css to generate checksum for.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in KS versions below 1.0, the build script is not quite ready. (Hence it not being a full stable release). However, I hope to have a release candidate of v.1.0 polished by the end of July 2012. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Sure. Want to kick the tires on a prerelease? Email me at ajkochanowicz@gmail.com and I'll hook you up. The build script should work at least minimally in the version I send you.